# Getting 500 Internal Server Error when using .htaccess file to remove PHP extension

Tags: php, .htaccess

Am trying to access a blog section of my website https://lordmanadventures.com/viewblog/1 but i keep on getting a 500 Internal Server Error. 
Am thinking the problem is with my .htaccess file. The weird thing is that if i change the url to this  https://lordmanadventures.com/viewblog.php/1 , it works. Below is my .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ viewblog.php?blog-id=$1  [L,QSA]
```

I have looked through various sites and solutions but can't seem to get it working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try changing your  regex to `^(.*)/?$` in the first rule so that it can match the traling slash separately.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i finally got it working. It seems that the way the rules are arranged from top to bottom matters. I removed the rewrite rule for the blog from the bottom, then added the page name. Then moved @SJacks answer of removing extension to the bottom et voilà!

```
# Start rewrite rules
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Blog
RewriteRule ^viewblog/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ viewblog.php?blog-id=$1  [L]

# Remove php extension
rewritecond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
rewriterule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,L]
rewriterule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for the assistance guys. Much appreciated.

Comment: Late reply. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to properly remove the PHP extension. After this specific page rewrites can be made. I didn't include anything on that because this should solve your problem. Let me know how you get on.

```
# Start rewrite rules
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Remove php extension
rewritecond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
rewriterule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,L]
rewriterule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the timely response. I have tried your solution but its still showing the 500 Internal Server Error.